# Connecting Athena and S3 in same Cloudformation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

From the documentation, [AWS::Athena::NamedQuery](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-athena-namedquery.html), it is unclear how to attach Athena to an S3 bucket specified in the same stack.

If I had to guess from the [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-athena-namedquery.html#aws-resource-athena-namedquery-examples), I would imagine that you can write a template like,

```
Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
       ... other params ...

  AthenaNamedQuery:
    Type: AWS::Athena::NamedQuery
    Properties:
      Database: "db_name"
      Name: "MostExpensiveWorkflow"
      QueryString: >
                    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db_name.test_table 
                    (...) LOCATION s3://.../path/to/folder/
```

Would a template like the above work? Upon stack creation, will the table `db_name.test_table` be available to run queries on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out the way you connect the S3 and Athena is to make a Glue table! How silly of me!! Of course Glue is how you connect things!

Sarcasm aside, this is a template that worked for me when using [AWS::Glue::Table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-table.html) and [AWS::Glue::Database](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-database.html),

```
Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  MyGlueDatabase:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Database
    Properties:
      DatabaseInput:
        Name: my-glue-database
        Description: "Glue beats tape"
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId

  MyGlueTable:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      DatabaseName: !Ref MyGlueDatabase
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      TableInput:
        Name: my-glue-table
        Parameters: { "classification" : "csv" }
        StorageDescriptor:
          Location:
            Fn::Sub: "s3://${MyS3Bucket}/"
          InputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat"
          OutputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
          SerdeInfo:
            Parameters: { "separatorChar" : "," }
            SerializationLibrary: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"
          StoredAsSubDirectories: false
          Columns:
            - Name: column0
              Type: string
            - Name: column1
              Type: string
```

After this, the database and table were in the AWS Athena Console!

Comment: Additionally, you can see [Sample AWS CloudFormation Template for an AWS Glue Database, Table, and Partition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-with-cloudformation-templates.html#sample-cfn-template-db-table-partition) which includes data partitioning.

Comment: Cheers @ignorance this helped me out. I was looking through the documentation on Athena and just getting lots on how we are supposed to set this up. Conclusion focus on Glue

Answer (score 0):

If the above doesn't help, you might need to add the workgroup as well.

```
GlueBucket:  
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:  
        BucketName: my-bucket
    GlueBucketPolicy:  
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref GlueBucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 's3:*'
              Resource:
                - 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*'
              Principal: '*'  
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 's3:*'
              Resource:
                - 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket'
              Principal: '*'                
    GlueDatabase:
      Type: AWS::Glue::Database
      Properties:
        DatabaseInput:
          Name: glue-database
        CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    GlueTable:
      Type: AWS::Glue::Table
      Properties:
        DatabaseName: !Ref GlueDatabase
        CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
        TableInput:
          Name: data
          Parameters: { "classification" : "json" }
          StorageDescriptor:
            Location: "s3://my-bucket/"
            InputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat"
            OutputFormat: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
            SerdeInfo:
              SerializationLibrary: "org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde"
            StoredAsSubDirectories: false
            Columns:
              - Name: siteid
                Type: string  
    MyAthenaWorkGroup:
      Type: AWS::Athena::WorkGroup
      Properties:
        Name: athena-workgroup
        State: ENABLED
        WorkGroupConfiguration:
          BytesScannedCutoffPerQuery: 200000000
          EnforceWorkGroupConfiguration: false
          PublishCloudWatchMetricsEnabled: false
          RequesterPaysEnabled: true
          ResultConfiguration:
            OutputLocation: "s3://athena-bucket/results/"
```