# AWS Glue+Athena skip header row

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena, aws-glue

As of [January 19, 2018 updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2018-01-19.html), Athena can skip the header row of files,

> Support for ignoring headers. You can use the `skip.header.line.count` property when defining tables, to allow Athena to ignore headers.

I use [AWS Glue in Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-table.html) to manage my Athena tables. Using the [Glue Table Input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-table-tableinput.html), how can I tell Athena to skip the header row?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basing off the full template for `AWS::Glue::Table` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47760146/3002273), making the change from,

```
Resources:
  ...
  MyGlueTable:
    ...
    Properties:
      ...
      TableInput:
        ...
        StorageDescriptor:
          ...
          SerdeInfo:
            Parameters: { "separatorChar" : "," }
```

To,

```
            Parameters:
              separatorChar : ","
              "skip.header.line.count" : 1
```

Does the trick.

Comment: skip.header.line.count needs to be given a string value. FYI