# How to skip top N rows in csv for AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

My csv file has some header information in first 7 rows.
Actual column name starts from 8th row, so how can I skip first 7 rows in AWS Glue?
any idea ?

Comment: This is a bit tricky considering sparks parallel nature and the way it shuffles your data across nodes. Maybe one solution you can try is to remove the lines based on a filter condition. Remove anything that starts with the pattern that matches your header lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file by providing custom schema and reading the file with different mode like:

```
schema=StructType([StructField('Id',StringType(), True),StructField('Name',StringType(), True)])

#now read your CSV as
df=spark.read.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").csv(path, schema=schema)

#now you will have dataframe rows which matches your schema only. If you still want to remove some top rows you can use

df=df.withColumn("Index",monotonically_increasing_id).filter('Index > 7).drop("Index")
```

There is no shortcut for this as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is answered in this answer: [AWS Glue+Athena skip header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866197/aws-glueathena-skip-header-row)

In the console it looks like this:
[Console with parameter added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8yTt.png)

In your case the 1 would be 7.

Comment: My experience has been that defining the header rows Serializer/Deserializer parameter for the Catalog/Athena as well as the footer table parameter that AWS added to the stack does alter the way that Athena queries source files from S3 but does not alter the behavior of Glue Jobs and it's unclear whether it alters the behavior of the crawler.